# Text in tree does not match text which is displayed

Tags: treeview, silktest

When creating a relation in SAP and in case there are several possible types of relations, SAP shows a dialog to choose the relation like this:

[image: Screenshot SAP create relation]

However, when I query the node text using `SapTree.getText()` of Silk4J, I get the following results:

```
U
    B ZE3 9V
    B ZE3 U
    B 003 O
```

Where does this text come from, what does it mean and how do I get the text that is displayed to the user?

I have tried

- there are no column names returned by `SapTree.getColumnNames()`
- there are no column titles returned by `SapTree.getColumnTitles()`
- `SapTre.getColumnHeaders()` returns two items, `HierarchyHeader` and `ListItems`. Calling `getItemText()` with any of those header names does not return the text displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click the relation and choose "Show keys":

[image: Screenshot SAP context menu on relation]

This results in

[image: Dialog showing keys]

which explains the text. It consists of three parts:

- `X` is the relationship type (`A`: bottom up, `B`: top down)
- `YYY` is the relationship (relations starting with `Z` are custom relations)
- `ZZ` is the type of the object to be linked (objects starting with `9` are custom objects)

To get the text displayed to the user:

- you can call `SapTree.getItemText(key, "1")` to get the relation text (e.g. `B ZE3 9V`)
- you can call `SapTree.getItemText(key, "2")` to get the human readable relation description (e.g. `beinhaltet`)
- you can call `SapTree.getItemText(key, "3")` to get the human readable target object text (e.g. `Externe Person`)